# Complicated JSON with Cakephp 3

Tags: php, mysql, json, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am working on a project which involves passing data "profiles" via JSON to a web application.  I am using Cakephp 3.0 and am very new to it.  I store the profiles in a mysql database and can easily query for the data and put it into a basic JSON format with each row being a separate value in the JSON:

Controller.php:

```
....
public function getProfileData()
    {
        $uid = $this->Auth->user('id');
        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
        $this->set('profile', $this->MapDisplay->find(
            'all',
            ['conditions' => 
                ['MapDisplay.user_id =' => $uid]
            ]
        )
        );
        $this->set('_serialize', ['profile']);
    }
....
```

get_profile_data.ctp:

```
<?= json_encode($profile); ?>
```

Which returns something like this:

```
{
"profile": [
    {
        "alert_id": 1,
        "alert_name": "Test",
        "user_id": 85,
        "initialized_time": "2017-03-24T00:00:00",
        "forecasted_time": "2017-03-24T00:10:00",
        "minimum_dbz_forecast": 0,
        "maximum_dbz_forecast": 10,
        "average_dbz_forecast": 5,
        "confidence_in_forecast": 0.99,
        "alert_lat": 44.3876,
        "alert_lon": -68.2039
    },
    {
        "alert_id": 1,
        "alert_name": "Test",
        "user_id": 85,
        "initialized_time": "2017-03-24T00:00:00",
        "forecasted_time": "2017-03-24T00:20:00",
        "minimum_dbz_forecast": 5,
        "maximum_dbz_forecast": 15,
        "average_dbz_forecast": 10,
        "confidence_in_forecast": 0.99,
        "alert_lat": 44.3876,
        "alert_lon": -68.2039
    },
    {
        "alert_id": 2,
        "alert_name": "Test2",
        "user_id": 85,
        "initialized_time": "2017-03-24T00:00:00",
        "forecasted_time": "2017-03-24T00:10:00",
        "minimum_dbz_forecast": 10,
        "maximum_dbz_forecast": 20,
        "average_dbz_forecast": 15,
        "confidence_in_forecast": 0.99,
        "alert_lat": 44.5876,
        "alert_lon": -68.1039
    },
    {
        "alert_id": 2,
        "alert_name": "Test2",
        "user_id": 85,
        "initialized_time": "2017-03-24T00:00:00",
        "forecasted_time": "2017-03-24T00:20:00",
        "minimum_dbz_forecast": 15,
        "maximum_dbz_forecast": 25,
        "average_dbz_forecast": 35,
        "confidence_in_forecast": 0.99,
        "alert_lat": 44.5876,
        "alert_lon": -68.1039
]
}
```

I am hoping to A) Easily call individual profiles instead of searching for unique profile ids and B) Only have to load one JSON file to get all profile contents.  An output of something like this would be more ideal:

```
 {
"profile": [
    {
        "alert_id": 1,
        "alert_name": "Test",
        "initialized_time":"2017-03-24T00:00:00",
        "alert_lat": 44.3876,
        "alert_lon": -68.2039,
        "profile_data": [
            {
                "forecasted_time": "2017-03-24T00:10:00",
                "minimum_dbz_forecast": 0,
                "maximum_dbz_forecast": 10,
                "average_dbz_forecast": 5,
                "confidence_in_forecast": 0.99
            },
            {
                "forecasted_time": "2017-03-24T00:20:00",
                "minimum_dbz_forecast": 5,
                "maximum_dbz_forecast": 15,
                "average_dbz_forecast": 10,
                "confidence_in_forecast": 0.99
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "alert_id": 2,
        "alert_name": "Test2",
        "initialized_time": "2017-03-24T00:00:00",
        "alert_lat": 44.5876,
        "alert_lon": -68.1039,
        "profile_data": [
            {
                "forecasted_time": "2017-03-24T00:10:00",
                "minimum_dbz_forecast": 10,
                "maximum_dbz_forecast": 20,
                "average_dbz_forecast": 15,
                "confidence_in_forecast": 0.99
            },
            {
                "forecasted_time": "2017-03-24T00:20:00",
                "minimum_dbz_forecast": 15,
                "maximum_dbz_forecast": 25,
                "average_dbz_forecast": 35,
                "confidence_in_forecast": 0.99
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

How would I go about querying my database and populating this JSON structure?  Are there any Cakephp tools that help do this?  Does reframing the JSON into this structure seem to make sense?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like you have a lot of duplicate data in your database, ie your schema isn't as normalized as it could be!?

Comment: This is true - I was going to try to get it working with just one table first (it seemed like it would be easier), then split the data into two tables with alert_id, alert_name, initialized_time, alert_lat, and alert_lon in one table and alert_id, forecasted_time, minimum_dbz_forecast, maximum_dbz_forecast, average_dbz_forecast, and confidence_in_forecast in another table (with the two "alert_id"s corresponding to each other).  Would it be easier to put this JSON together in the latter case?

Comment: Most likely, yes. You'd just have to set up the [**associations**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html) properly, and [**contain**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#loading-associations) the associated table in your find, and in case the property name for the association would be `profile_data`, you wouldn't even have to modify the results at all.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me the right way!  I got it working.  I'll write up a thorough response to what I did for people who might have this problem in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to user ndm, I realized there were a few problems with my approach.  I thought having all data in one table would simplify things, but in reality it would make things more complicated and require redundant data storage (eg, a latitude and longitude value stored for every profile entry, instead of just once in a separate table).

ndm also mentioned

> You'd just have to set up the [associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html) properly, and [contain](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#loading-associations) the associated >table in your find, and in case the property name for the association would be >profile_data, you wouldn't even have to modify the results at all.

After altering the Table Model file, I had this for a new "ProfileDataTable.php" file:

```
class ProfileDataTable extends Table
{

/**
 * Initialize method
 *
 * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
 * @return void
 */
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);        

    $this->setTable('profile_data');

    $this->setDisplayField('title');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('alert_id');
    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->belongsTo('AlertData', [
        'foreignKey' => 'alert_id'
    ]);
}

}
```

And this for a new "AlertDataTable.php" file:

```
class AlertDataTable extends Table
{

/**
 * Initialize method
 *
 * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
 * @return void
 */
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->setTable('alert_data');

    $this->setDisplayField('title');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('alert_id');
    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->hasMany('ProfileData', [
        'foreignKey' => 'alert_id'
    ]);
}

}
```

The important lines here being "belongsTo" and "hasMany".

I then was able to alter my query and use "contain" to easily link the two tables together and get the JSON formatted exactly how I wanted:

```
$this->AlertData->find(
        'all',
        ['conditions' => 
            ['AlertData.user_id =' => $uid],
        'contain' => 
            ['ProfileData']
        ]
    );
```